# cygwin gjs segfault: egList.js, egSpawn.js and egSearch.js

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, gjs

gjs-examples (https://github.com/optimisme/gjs-examples): egList.js, egSpawn.js and egSearch.js are cause segmentation fault.

gjs version is 1.44.0-1 (cygwin)

methods that cause segmentation fault:

- egList.js
   (Gtk.TreeViewColumn)col.set_cell_data_func
- egSearch.js
   (Gtk.FlowBox)flow.set_filter_func
- egSpawn.js
   (Spawn.SpawnReader)reader.spawn

**gdb output egList.js:**
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
gjs_invoke_c_function at /usr/src/debug/gjs-1.44.0-1/gi/function.cpp:1117
             gjs_callback_trampoline_unref(trampoline);
print trampoline
(GjsCallbackTrampoline *) 0x0 
print function->invoker.native_address 
(gpointer) gtk_tree_view_column_set_cell_data_func

The same situation repeated in other cases: egSpawn.js and egSearch.js

Ununtu 14 - Ubuntu 16: examples work fine
I can't understand reason this behavior.

> UPDATE: full gdb output

```
    (gdb) r
Starting program: /usr/bin/gjs egList.js
[New Thread 4172.0x1640]
[New Thread 4172.0x1784]
[New Thread 4172.0xb90]
[New Thread 4172.0x15b4]
[New Thread 4172.0x14dc]
[New Thread 4172.0x16c0]
[New Thread 4172.0x1358]
[New Thread 4172.0xe4c]
[New Thread 4172.0xf60]
[New Thread 4172.0x1510]
[New Thread 4172.0x12e8]
[New Thread 4172.0x968]
[New Thread 4172.0xe64]
[New Thread 4172.0x1614]
Gjs-Message: JS LOG: getBody_14

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
gjs_invoke_c_function (context=0x6ff00000008, context@entry=0x6000b5150, function=function@entry=0x6002a1cc0,
    obj=obj@entry=0x6ffffc71ac0, js_argc=1, js_argc@entry=2, js_argv=js_argv@entry=0x600139cc0, js_rval=js_rval@entry=0xffff9f60,
    r_value=r_value@entry=0x0) at /usr/src/debug/gjs-1.44.0-1/gi/function.cpp:1117
1117                        gjs_callback_trampoline_unref(trampoline);
(gdb) bt
#0  gjs_invoke_c_function (context=0x6ff00000008, context@entry=0x6000b5150, function=function@entry=0x6002a1cc0,
    obj=obj@entry=0x6ffffc71ac0, js_argc=1, js_argc@entry=2, js_argv=js_argv@entry=0x600139cc0, js_rval=js_rval@entry=0xffff9f60,
    r_value=r_value@entry=0x0) at /usr/src/debug/gjs-1.44.0-1/gi/function.cpp:1117
#1  0x0000000577de72c8 in function_call (context=0x6000b5150, js_argc=2, vp=0x600139cb0)
    at /usr/src/debug/gjs-1.44.0-1/gi/function.cpp:1322
#2  0x00000003eb882c2a in cygmozjs-24!_ZN2js6InvokeEP9JSContextN2JS8CallArgsENS_14MaybeConstructE () from /usr/bin/cygmozjs-24.dll
#3  0x00000003eb678565 in cygmozjs-24!_Z9js_strtodP9JSContextPKwS2_PS2_Pd () from /usr/bin/cygmozjs-24.dll
#4  0x00000003eb8fa568 in cygmozjs-24!_ZN2js9RunScriptEP9JSContextRNS_8RunStateE () from /usr/bin/cygmozjs-24.dll
#5  0x00000003eb882d84 in cygmozjs-24!_ZN2js6InvokeEP9JSContextN2JS8CallArgsENS_14MaybeConstructE () from /usr/bin/cygmozjs-24.dll
#6  0x00000003eb730935 in cygmozjs-24!_ZN2js28CallOrConstructBoundFunctionEP9JSContextjPN2JS5ValueE ()
   from /usr/bin/cygmozjs-24.dll
#7  0x00000003eb882c6f in cygmozjs-24!_ZN2js6InvokeEP9JSContextN2JS8CallArgsENS_14MaybeConstructE () from /usr/bin/cygmozjs-24.dll
#8  0x00000003eb882f3a in cygmozjs-24!_ZN2js6InvokeEP9JSContextRKN2JS5ValueES5_jPS3_S6_ () from /usr/bin/cygmozjs-24.dll
#9  0x00000003eb5f1bcd in cygmozjs-24!_Z20JS_CallFunctionValueP9JSContextP8JSObjectN2JS5ValueEjPS4_S5_ ()
   from /usr/bin/cygmozjs-24.dll
#10 0x0000000577dd9dfa in gjs_call_function_value (context=0x6000b5150, obj=0x0, fval=..., argc=1, argv=0xffffb330,
    rval=0xffffb360) at /usr/src/debug/gjs-1.44.0-1/gjs/jsapi-util.cpp:724
#11 0x0000000577de3f1c in gjs_closure_invoke (closure=0x6001dd6a0, argc=1, argv=0xffffb330, retval=0xffffb360)
    at /usr/src/debug/gjs-1.44.0-1/gi/closure.cpp:282
#12 0x0000000577df1b93 in closure_marshal (closure=0x600087600, return_value=0xffffb5a0, n_param_values=1,
    param_values=<optimized out>, invocation_hint=0xffffb5a0, marshal_data=0x57) at /usr/src/debug/gjs-1.44.0-1/gi/value.cpp:160
#13 0x00000003f17c5a0c in g_closure_invoke () from /usr/bin/cyggobject-2.0-0.dll
#14 0x00000003f17d6912 in g_signal_handler_disconnect () from /usr/bin/cyggobject-2.0-0.dll
#15 0x00000003f17de9c8 in g_signal_emit_valist () from /usr/bin/cyggobject-2.0-0.dll
#16 0x00000003f17dec38 in g_signal_emit () from /usr/bin/cyggobject-2.0-0.dll
#17 0x00000003f2222a11 in g_application_register () from /usr/bin/cyggio-2.0-0.dll
#18 0x00000003f2223112 in g_application_open () from /usr/bin/cyggio-2.0-0.dll
#19 0x00000003f2223449 in g_application_run () from /usr/bin/cyggio-2.0-0.dll
#20 0x00000003f45a4791 in ffi_call_win64 () from /usr/bin/cygffi-6.dll
#21 0x00000003f45a446c in ffi_closure_free () from /usr/bin/cygffi-6.dll
#22 0x00000003f45a45e2 in ffi_call () from /usr/bin/cygffi-6.dll
#23 0x0000000577de6039 in gjs_invoke_c_function (context=0x0, context@entry=0x6000b5150, function=function@entry=0x600056b60,
    obj=obj@entry=0x6ffffc71460, js_argc=4051503217, js_argc@entry=1, js_argv=js_argv@entry=0x6001399f8,
    js_rval=js_rval@entry=0xffffbee0, r_value=r_value@entry=0x0) at /usr/src/debug/gjs-1.44.0-1/gi/function.cpp:999
#24 0x0000000577de72c8 in function_call (context=0x6000b5150, js_argc=1, vp=0x6001399e8)
    at /usr/src/debug/gjs-1.44.0-1/gi/function.cpp:1322
#25 0x00000003eb882c2a in cygmozjs-24!_ZN2js6InvokeEP9JSContextN2JS8CallArgsENS_14MaybeConstructE () from /usr/bin/cygmozjs-24.dll
#26 0x00000003eb678565 in cygmozjs-24!_Z9js_strtodP9JSContextPKwS2_PS2_Pd () from /usr/bin/cygmozjs-24.dll
#27 0x00000003eb8fa568 in cygmozjs-24!_ZN2js9RunScriptEP9JSContextRNS_8RunStateE () from /usr/bin/cygmozjs-24.dll
#28 0x00000003eb6f7f23 in cygmozjs-24!_ZN2js13ExecuteKernelEP9JSContextN2JS6HandleIP8JSScriptEER8JSObjectRKNS2_5ValueENS_11ExecuteTypeENS_16AbstractFramePtrEPS9_ () from /usr/bin/cygmozjs-24.dll
#29 0x00000003eb8a216e in cygmozjs-24!_ZN2js7ExecuteEP9JSContextN2JS6HandleIP8JSScriptEER8JSObjectPNS2_5ValueE ()
   from /usr/bin/cygmozjs-24.dll
#30 0x00000003eb6ce6a2 in cygmozjs-24!_ZN2JS8EvaluateEP9JSContextNS_6HandleIP8JSObjectEENS_14CompileOptionsEPKwmPNS_5ValueE ()
   from /usr/bin/cygmozjs-24.dll
#31 0x00000003eb6ce5d2 in cygmozjs-24!_ZN2JS8EvaluateEP9JSContextNS_6HandleIP8JSObjectEENS_14CompileOptionsEPKcmPNS_5ValueE ()
   from /usr/bin/cygmozjs-24.dll
#32 0x0000000577dda05d in gjs_eval_with_scope (context=0x6000b5150, object=0x6ffffc36160,
    script=0x600078c0f "\n/*\nGJS example showing how to build Gtk javascript applications\nusing Gtk TreeView and ListStore\n\nRun it with:\n    gjs egList.js\n*/\n\nconst Gio   = imports.gi.Gio;\nconst GLib  = imports.gi.GLib;\nconst"..., script_len=3777,
    filename=0xffffcc60 "egList.js", retval_p=0xffffcb00) at /usr/src/debug/gjs-1.44.0-1/gjs/jsapi-util.cpp:1325
#33 0x0000000577dd35d8 in gjs_context_eval (js_context=0x60008b000,
    script=0x600078c00 "#!/usr/bin/gjs\n\n/*\nGJS example showing how to build Gtk javascript applications\nusing Gtk TreeView and ListStore\n\nRun it with:\n    gjs egList.js\n*/\n\nconst Gio   = imports.gi.Gio;\nconst GLib  = imports"..., script_len=3792,
    filename=0xffffcc60 "egList.js", exit_status_p=0xffffcb94, error=0xffffcb98) at /usr/src/debug/gjs-1.44.0-1/gjs/context.cpp:645
#34 0x0000000100401b07 in main (argc=1, argv=0xffffcc28) at /usr/src/debug/gjs-1.44.0-1/gjs/console.cpp:147
(gdb) print trampoline
$1 = (GjsCallbackTrampoline *) 0x0
(gdb) print function->invoker.native_address
$2 = (gpointer) 0x3eff083a0 <gtk_tree_view_column_set_cell_data_func>
(gdb) list
1112                    if (closure) {
1113                        GjsCallbackTrampoline *trampoline = (GjsCallbackTrampoline *) closure->user_data;
1114                        /* CallbackTrampolines are refcounted because for notified/async closures
1115                           it is possible to destroy it while in call, and therefore we cannot check
1116                           its scope at this point */
1117                        gjs_callback_trampoline_unref(trampoline);
1118                        arg->v_pointer = NULL;
1119                    }
1120                } else if (param_type == PARAM_ARRAY) {
1121                    gsize length;
```

Comment: Sorry, I cannot understand where is the segmentation fault, could you reformulate your question defining your call stack until segmentation fault?

Comment: @urlordi topic updated